# ISNA + Vlookup function not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2016

I have two separate excel workbooks,I need to find the common values between the two file on two separate columns.

Book 1:-

```
Column 1(A)  Column2(B)  Column 3(C)
Data         123456D     123456
Data         234567D     234567
Data         456789D     456789
```

Book 2:-

```
Column1(B)  Column (n)
123456  
234567  
456789  
552244
665897
```

Now here, im trying to update the data from column 1 of book 1 into column 1 of Book 2

Book 1 contains 7000 entries

Book 2 contains 10000 entries

In book 1, ive extracted the data from Column 2 into column 3 by extracting the 1st 12 digits, im then comparing the Column 2 book 1 with column1 book 2(to match the data). To do this i use the following formula on column (n) of book 2:-

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B11,'Book1, Sheet2'!$C$4:$C$7727,3,FALSE)))
```

My ideal result for this should be that the data in field(n) of book 2 should show false if it is an exact match and true otherwise.

My problem here is in book 2, upon copying the formula down column N all fields are showing False(exact match) which is not the case!..

The fields that dont match between the 2 books should show a TRUE against them in book 2.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try it this way:

=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B11,'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2'!$C$4:$C$7727,1,FALSE)))
'                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^
```

The first correction is the way you reference an external workbook.

The second is you should look at column `1` because the range you're searching consists of only one column

You can also use `Match` and `ISNUMBER`, with a simpler form:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B11,'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2'!$C$4:$C$7727,0))
```

Comment: It still does not work, i tried both the queries you provided but still no luck...
Ive even tried copying the data from both the sheets to a fresh sheet but it still does not help...

Comment: Did you check the names of the worksheets, workbooks and the correct range addresses? also, the given formula assumes that `Book1.xlsx` is open. If it is closed, you will need to add the path, or let Excel add it automatically when you close `Book1.xlsx` but it needs to be open when you type in the formula.@user2269061

Comment: Im trying this in a single workbook now, traversing the data through two sheets, so the referencing is easier.... Now, the 1st formula worked, but it dint work correctly.... i'm supposed to get a false against 7725 entries but it only works for 5727 entries, everything else becomes True... is there anyway i could share the file im working on ?